# JavaScript append additional script to native classList remove and toggle methods or complete replacement?

Tags: javascript

When using the methods `remove` or `toggle` from the `classList` object in Gecko browsers if there are no more classes assigned to the target element that element will still have a `class` attribute however it will be empty. This makes for messy code when submitting serialized code to the server and search engines probably don't appreciate empty attributes either (code to content ratio).

Is it possible to add additional code to the native methods `remove` or `toggle` of the `classList` object to remove the `class` attribute from an element if it is empty somehow or will I have to write my own replacement script for those methods?

- If it can be done by *appending to the native `classList` object* then I need to know *how* to append the native object's existing methods.
- If I need to outright replace the native methods `remove` or `toggle` how would do I implement it so that regardless of *how* the method is accessed (`getElementById('a').classList`, `getElementsByTagName('a').classList`, `‎getElementsByClassName('a').classList`, etc) it will still work?

No frameworks.

---

How to serialize (X)HTML in JavaScript:

```
if (typeof window.XMLSerializer!=='undefined')
{
 var r = document.getElementById('example_id');
 var xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(r);
}
```

Comment: Emptying a `classList` is akin to `.className = ""`, which does create the attribute as well - and there's nothing wrong with that. If you want to avoid empty attributes, you rather should omit them from the serialisation process.

Comment: If you can post your serialisation code, I can should you how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather remove empty `class` attributes before serialising the DOM, than try to overwrite `classList` methods. Doing so is quite simple:

```
var r = document.getElementById('example_id');
var els = [].slice.call(r.querySelectorAll('[class=""]').concat(r.className ? [] : [r]);
els.forEach(function(el) {
    el.removeAttribute('class');
});
var xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(r);
```